# Standalone child in backtick command

Tags: linux, perl, fork

Here is a main script that exec the perl script "fork.pl"
    #!/bin/bash

```
OUTPUT=`./fork.pl`
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

And the fork.pl:
    #!/usr/bin/perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX;

my $pid = fork();

if ($pid == 0) {
    sleep(5);
    print("child: $pid\n");
}

else {
    print("parent: $pid\n")
}
```

The backtick implies a wait, but I would like to not wait for the last child.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to detach from parent and to redirect the input/output :

```
if ($pid == 0) {
    my $mysid = setsid();
    open (STDIN, "</dev/null");
    open (STDOUT, ">/dev/null");
    open (STDERR, ">&STDOUT");

    sleep(5);
    print("child: $pid\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to not to wait for the termination, is to start in the background while redirecting the output to a file. Then try to read the lines with the shell's `read`.

For example, a hack to read the first line:

```
./fork.pl > temp.out &
sleep 1
read OUTPUT < temp.out
```

Alternatively, without `sleep`, but limited to a `do`/`done` block:

```
./fork.pl | while read OUTPUT; do
     # use $OUTPUT here
     break   # first line only, or loop conditionally
done
```

Comment: I must apologize because my question was ambiguous. I wanted to keep the backtick call (I can't change it).

Comment: What can you change? The `echo`?